# Compass Installed on WebSpace: Command not found

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, rubygems, compass

I want to use Compass in my webspace on a hosted server (no root access). I followed tutorial provided by the hosting company but had no success so far:

In my home dir I created a .gem dir and a .gemrc file:

```
/* .gemrc in home dir */

gemhome: &GemHome /my/home/dir/.gem
gempath:
   - *GemHome
   - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

The .bashrc file:

```
export GEM_HOME=/my/home/dir/.gem
export GEM_PATH=/my/home/dir/.gem:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

Some checks after re-connecting:

```
[~] echo $GEM_HOME
/my/home/dir/.gem

[~] echo $GEM_PATH
/my/home/dir/.gem:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

[~] echo $PATH
?/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Installing Compass

```
[~] gem install compass

Successfully installed compass-core-1.0.3
Successfully installed compass-import-once-1.0.5
Successfully installed chunky_png-1.3.5
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.9.6
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.10
Successfully installed rb-inotify-0.9.5
Successfully installed compass-1.0.3
7 gems installed
```

Check installation

```
[~] gem list compass -d

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

compass (1.0.3)
    Authors: Chris Eppstein, Scott Davis, Eric M. Suzanne, Brandon
    Mathis, Nico Hagenburger
    Homepage: http://compass-style.org
    Installed at: /my/home/dir/.gem

    A Real Stylesheet Framework

compass-core (1.0.3)
    Authors: Chris Eppstein, Scott Davis, Eric M. Suzanne, Brandon
    Mathis
    Homepage: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/
    License: MIT
    Installed at: /my/home/dir/.gem

    The Compass core stylesheet library

compass-import-once (1.0.5)
    Author: Chris Eppstein
    Homepage:
    https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/tree/master/import-once
    License: MIT
    Installed at: /my/home/dir/.gem

    Speed up your Sass compilation by making @import only import each
    file once.


[~] gem which compass
/my/home/dir/.gem/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb
```

But Compass cannot be used:

```
[~] compass
-bash: compass: command not found
```

Any idea what else I have to do to get compass running? I found several other discussions about this topic but all solutions targeted servers with root access. Since I do not have root access to the server: Any other solutions?

EDIT: Some more information

```
ls -al ~/.gem
total 32
drwxr-x---  8 u100170 nobody 4096 Nov 19 08:43 .
drwx--x--- 11 u100170 nobody 4096 Nov 19 09:13 ..
drwxr-x---  2 u100170 nobody 4096 Nov 19 08:49 bin
drwxr-x---  2 u100170 nobody 4096 Nov 19 08:49 cache
drwxr-x---  9 u100170 nobody 4096 Nov 19 08:49 doc
drwxr-x--- 10 u100170 nobody 4096 Nov 19 08:49 gems
drwxr-x---  2 u100170 nobody 4096 Nov 19 08:49 specifications
drwxr-x---  3 u100170 nobody 4096 Nov 19 08:43 specs

cd ~/.gem/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/
ls -al
drwxr-x--- 3 u100170 nobody 4096 Nov 19 08:49 .
drwxr-x--- 6 u100170 nobody 4096 Nov 19 08:49 ..
drwxr-x--- 9 u100170 nobody 4096 Nov 19 08:49 compass
-rw-r--r-- 1 u100170 nobody  676 Nov 19 08:49 compass.rb

compass
-bash: compass: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .gem location is not appended to your environmental variable. As seen from the output `echo $PATH` it isn't appended to your `$PATH` environmental variable.

Try appending it to your `$PATH` variable

```
export GEM_HOME=/my/home/dir/.gem/bin
export GEM_PATH=/my/home/dir/.gem:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

PATH=$PATH:GEM_HOME:GEM_PATH
export PATH
```

Finally do a `source ~/.bashrc`

**Update**

Appending the correct executable path to the `$PATH` environment variable will make your executable available within the shell environment.

In this specific scenario the executable location is `/my/home/dir/.gem/bin`

Comment: Thanks, but this did not solve the problem. Still command not found. It does not matter if `PATH=$PATH:GEM_HOME:GEM_PATH` or `PATH=$PATH:$GEM_HOME:$GEM_PATH` is used.

Comment: Yes that shouldn't be an issue. Are you sure the ```compass``` binary is there your location? ```/my/home/dir/.gem```. Also have you tried opening up a new terminal session?

Comment: Yes, see the result of `gem which compass` in the "Check install" section: `/my/home/dir/.gem/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb`. I also re-connected to the server several times. The result is always the same.

Comment: Also make sure ```compass``` is executable and also try appending the location to the ```$PATH``` manually, not using another variable.

Comment: Can you also post the result of ```ls -al /my/home/dir/.gem```?

Comment: I think the executable binary should be inside ```/my/home/dir/.gem/bin``` try appending ```bin``` path as well. Don't forget to ```source```.

Comment: That worked, Thank you very much! Maybe you want to add this to your answer to make it easier to find for others.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is dated, but after researching it, it was similar to my problem.

While searching for bin, I found it on openSuse 15.4 under: `/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin`

To find it, I used the commands:

```bash
find  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/  -type f | grep compass
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin
export PATH
```

Hope this will be useful to others.